# How to extract a HTML tag pattern multiple times from a string?

Tags: python, html, regex

I've got this pattern based on which I want to search a string to find all matches. After using `findall()`, only the last one matched is printed.

The string which I want to process is below:

`'<inventor sequence="001" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Li</last-name><first-name>Shuo</first-name><address><city>Beijing</city><country>CN</country></address></addressbook></inventor><inventor sequence="002" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Liu</last-name><first-name>Xin Peng</first-name><address><city>Beijing</city><country>CN</country></address></addressbook></inventor><inventor sequence="003" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Sun</last-name><first-name>Sheng Yan</first-name><address><city>Beijing</city><country>CN</country></address></addressbook></inventor><inventor sequence="004" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Wang</last-name><first-name>Hua</first-name><address><city>Littleton</city><state>MA</state><country>US</country></address></addressbook></inventor><inventor sequence="005" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Wang</last-name><first-name>Jun</first-name><address><city>Littleton</city><state>MA</state><country>US</country></address></addressbook></inventor>'`

I try to use the following code to extract all inventors from the string.

```py
INVENTORS_CONTENT_PATTERN = re.compile('<inventor sequence=".*" designation=".*">(.*?)</inventor>')

re.findall(INVENTORS_CONTENT_PATTERN, data)
```

The result I get is the last one matched, not all the inventors from data:

```html
['<addressbook><last-name>Wang</last-name><first-name>Jun</first-name><address><city>Littleton</city><state>MA</state><country>US</country></address></addressbook>']
```

Comment: The wildcard in `designation=".*"` ends up matching the middle 90% of the text.

Comment: Using regex to parse a nested structure such as HTML is a recipe for heartbreak.  Consider using a purpose-built xml/html parser.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This expression might be closer to what you have in mind:

```
<inventor sequence="[^"]*" designation="[^"]*">(.*?)<\/inventor>
```

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r'<inventor sequence="[^"]*" designation="[^"]*">(.*?)<\/inventor>'
test_str = """
<inventor sequence="001" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Li</last-name><first-name>Shuo</first-name><address><city>Beijing</city><country>CN</country></address></addressbook></inventor><inventor sequence="002" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Liu</last-name><first-name>Xin Peng</first-name><address><city>Beijing</city><country>CN</country></address></addressbook></inventor><inventor sequence="003" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Sun</last-name><first-name>Sheng Yan</first-name><address><city>Beijing</city><country>CN</country></address></addressbook></inventor><inventor sequence="004" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Wang</last-name><first-name>Hua</first-name><address><city>Littleton</city><state>MA</state><country>US</country></address></addressbook></inventor><inventor sequence="005" designation="us-only"><addressbook><last-name>Wang</last-name><first-name>Jun</first-name><address><city>Littleton</city><state>MA</state><country>US</country></address></addressbook></inventor>

"""
print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['<addressbook><last-name>Li</last-name><first-name>Shuo</first-name><address><city>Beijing</city><country>CN</country></address></addressbook>', '<addressbook><last-name>Liu</last-name><first-name>Xin Peng</first-name><address><city>Beijing</city><country>CN</country></address></addressbook>', '<addressbook><last-name>Sun</last-name><first-name>Sheng Yan</first-name><address><city>Beijing</city><country>CN</country></address></addressbook>', '<addressbook><last-name>Wang</last-name><first-name>Hua</first-name><address><city>Littleton</city><state>MA</state><country>US</country></address></addressbook>', '<addressbook><last-name>Wang</last-name><first-name>Jun</first-name><address><city>Littleton</city><state>MA</state><country>US</country></address></addressbook>']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ne4YGB/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/ne4YGB/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---